# Uniform convergence of the series with sin

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I am strugging with the following problem: Show whether the series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{-1/2}[\sin (\frac x {2k})-\sin (\frac x {2k-1})]
$$
converges uniformly on $\mathbb R$.

It is easy to see that the series converges pointwise, using the following estimate:
$$
|\sin (\frac x {2k})-\sin (\frac x {2k-1})|\leq C|x|k^{-2}.
$$
But if I attempt to show that the series converges uniformly, I have to use better estimates that deal with large values of $x$. Any suggestions?